# In using the Mapkit, I can see the fully scrollable map however no Apple headquarters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mapkit

I have tried it both on an actual device (iPad) and the iPhone simulator (ios 4)

I see the map but no Apple headquarters (blue pin) even if I zoom in.

In my OnViewLoad function I have:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;

[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
```

Comment: The first rule of Apple Headquarters is:  we do not talk about Apple Headquarters.

Comment: YOu should provide more information or more code. Are you looking for the Apple's Headquarters in Cupertino? Your code doesnt really say much for what you are looking for specifically.

Comment: On the device, do you see a blue dot at your location?  Is Location Services turned on in Settings?

Comment: Location Services is turned on and I do not see the blue dot. I am not looking for anything specifically other than being able to use the above code in a simulator to see the blue dot (default of which is apple head quarters)

Comment: The above code looks fine.  It may be something else.  How is mapView declared in the .h file?  Does the map appear as hybrid?  Does the Apple sample app CurrentAddress work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `-mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method, return nil if the annotation is a userLocation object:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isMemberOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    // your normal code
}
```

This is needed to make sure, the iOS default implementation is used to show the blue userLocation dot.